# al vincular la hoja de HTML a CSS los cambios aplicados a CSS no se ven cuando actualizo el index.html en google / firefox

Tags: css, html5, sublimetext3, href

Buenas por mas que cambio la dirección:

al efectuar cambios en el CSS ejemplo

estos cambios al abrir la pagina en google  los cambios o los colores siguen igual en resumen no puedo hacer  cambios en el css estos no se aplican

o quizás algo estoy haciendo mal 
soy nuevo en esto, programa que utilizo Sublime text 3

Comment: usa !important en el estilo

Comment: Posible duplicado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723801/file-not-updating-on-localhost

Comment: Puede ser tan simple como pulsar la tecla `control` + `F5` para refrescar, la cache en ocasiones nos juega sucio, pero es por ella misma que muchas cosas funcionan mas rápido.

Comment: cambia la opción del cache en network para desarrollar esto como jode: https://i.imgur.com/G328dlk.png

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada asegúrate de que incluyas tu código CSS **dentro de la etiqueta `<head>`**, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

Ejemplo utilizando la etiqueta `style`:

```
<head>
   ...
   <style type="text/css">
       ...
   </style>
   ...
</head>
```

De igual manera puedes incluir tu archivo .css utilizando `link` (esta forma es la más recomendable), un ejemplo:

```
<head>
   ...
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
   ...
</head>
```

En caso de que aún así no puedas ver los cambios entonces tienes que forzar la recarga de la página, en Google Chrome intenta presionando `Ctrl + F5`.

Comment: gracias ya lo solucione, el  estilos.css lo deje en la misma carpeta del index.html porque antes el estilos.css lo tenia en una carpeta "css" y el href="css/estilos.css,   y como deje el estilos .css en la misma carpeta del index html y cambie el href="estilos.css" y ahora si puedo ver los cambios que aplico en css quizas no se vincular el estilos.css cuando este se encuentra en otra carpeta.

Answer (score 0):

En google chrome normalmente se almacenan datos de cache que impiden actualizar rapidamente los cambios realizados en la hoja de estilos, puedes desactivar la cache de esta manera.

presiona el boton F12 y luego en la ventana del inspector de elementos te vas a la pestaña "network" y marcas la opcion "disable cache"

Answer (score 0):

Si la etiqueta `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>` está bien puesta intenta copiar el `css/main.css` (o la dirección que tengas) remplazando el index.html en el navegador. Si no te aparece tu pagina de estilos hay algo mal en la dirección puesta.

También puede ser el cache de Chrome, puedes probar con

- CTRL + SHIFT + R
- F12 y te vas a la pestaña `network`, `disable cache` y actualizas la pagina.